# How to simply move an SKNode?

Tags: sprite-kit

So i'm a beginner in Swift, and have been trying to make a game involving two characters. The bodies of both characters consist of a head and body SKSpriteNode, tied together with a regular SKNode. When I touch the left side of the screen, I want the player to move to the left, and so on. I'm not sure if i'm just missing something, but I can't seem to get the character to move anywhere using the applyImpulse method.

```
var playerNode = SKNode()
var playerBody = SKSpriteNode()
var playerHead = SKSpriteNode()

var opponentNode = SKNode()
var opponentBody = SKSpriteNode()
var opponentHead = SKSpriteNode()

var ground = SKSpriteNode()

override public func didMove(to view: SKView)
{
    playerNode = self.childNode(withName: "playerNode")!
    playerBody = playerNode.childNode(withName: "playerBody") as! SKSpriteNode
    playerHead = playerNode.childNode(withName: "playerHead") as! SKSpriteNode

    opponentNode = self.childNode(withName: "opponentNode")!
    opponentBody = opponentNode.childNode(withName: "opponentBody") as! SKSpriteNode
    opponentHead = opponentNode.childNode(withName: "opponentHead") as! SKSpriteNode
}

override public func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    for touch in touches
    {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if (location.x < 0)
        {
            playerNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -10, dy: 0))
        }
        else if (location.x > 0)
        {
            playerNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 0))
        }
    }
}

override public func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    playerNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have they physics bodies?

Comment: If you just want them to move 10 pixels you might use playerNode.run(SKAction.move(by:....   If you really want to apply an impulse, 1) make sure they have physics bodies and your physics world is set up first and 2), try applying a lot bigger impulse to test.  10 is a pretty small number depending on the mass of your physics bodies.